# play audio file in twilio conference

Tags: audio, twilio, conference

I'm looking for an example of how to play an audio file during a twilio conference session.  I'd like to play the audio file into the conference at the push of a button by one of the participants.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an article for how to do a roll call during a conference that will give you an idea of how to manage the workflow (you obviously just want the user to hear the played message, and not need to parse the calls):

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/roll-call-roger-stringer-shows-you-how-to-take-a-headcount-during-a-twilio-conference-call.html

Basically you have the user exit the conference on the keypress, have the message played, then the user rejoin the conference. If you want it to play for all users, it would disrupt the audio of the conference if you need the record feature for it.